# SQL Sorting within a sort

Tags: mysql, sql

Okay, this should be a fairly easy question I think, but haven't been able to figure it out yet.

I have a table entitled Staff. The staff DESC is below:

```
SQL> DESC Staff
Name                                      Null?    Type
----------------------------------------- -------- ----------
SNO                                       NOT NULL CHAR(5)
FNAME                                              VARCHAR2(3
LNAME                                              VARCHAR2(3
POSITION                                           VARCHAR2(1
SEX                                                CHAR(1)
DOB                                                DATE
SALARY                                             NUMBER(9)
BNO                                                CHAR(4)
```

Here is the current query I am using:

```
SELECT bNo, lName||' '||fName, position, salary
FROM Staff
WHERE bNo 'b009'
OR bNo = 'b005'
ORDER BY 
    case position
        when 'Manager' then 1
        when 'Secretary' then 2
        when 'Supervisor' then 3
        when 'Assistant' then 4
    else 99
end;
```

The problem I am having is that within each position group, I need to sort by lName as well. Any tips would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just add `lName` as a second `ORDER BY` column.

```
ORDER  BY CASE position
            WHEN 'Manager' THEN 1
            WHEN 'Secretary' THEN 2
            WHEN 'Supervisor' THEN 3
            WHEN 'Assistant' THEN 4
            ELSE 99
          END,
          lName;
```

Comment: Outstanding. That was MUCH easier than I was making it out to be. Thanks a ton for the help.